# Bind nginx on the same port for tcp and http

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have compiled nginx with the tcp_proxy_module by following this guide : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102110/nginx-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-and-enable-ssl-wss

What I want to do is to be able to forward :

```
TCP  url1.com:443 --forward to websocket--> 1234
HTTP url2.com:443 proxy localhost:1235
HTTP url3.com:443 proxy localhost:1236
```

The HTTP part works as expected since it's a different server_name. But the problem is with the TCP proxy, i'm getting :

Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)

How would I achieve that goal ?

-- edit : from the module's github https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module

> You can't use the same listening port with HTTP modules.

Comment: Like the documentation says, you can't do that. It makes as much sense as two different people using the same telephone to call two different persons at the same time.

Comment: It can't be done this way I know, I posted myself the answer... Maybe there's an alternative with some other tool ?

Comment: I don't know how to put it any clearer - it doesn't work because it doesn't work because that's not how it works.

Comment: I configured nginx on a second server to proxy. Guess it's the only way..

Comment: @Bastien974 Another option could be to setup a second ip address to your network interface.

Comment: I think you are being a bit harsh. Everything is possible. And it could make sense in some cases.
NginX could be able to separate http traffic from tcp.
I was looking for the exact same thing for jitsi videobridge: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-videobridge/blob/master/doc/http.md
They do it in java, so why not in NginX?
But yeah, I understand that this module can't do it.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentionned, [from the doc](https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module/blob/master/README) :

> Note, You can't use the same listening port with HTTP modules.

So, what you want to do is not possible.

---

An option could be to setup a second IP address on your network interface.

let's say that :

- `192.168.0.10` is the primary ip (that will serve your HTTPS web site)
- `192.168.0.20` is the secondary ip (that will serve your TCP websocket)

  ```
  tcp {
     upstream websockets {
       ....
     }
     server {
       server_name url1.com;
       listen 192.168.0.20:443;
     }
  }

  http {
     server {
        server_name  url2.com;
        listen 192.168.0.10:443;
        ....
     }

     server {
        server_name  url3.com;
        listen 192.168.0.10:443;
        ....
     }
   }
  ```