# Nginx - possible to serve http and tcp over same port?

Tags: nginx

I do realise this question has been asked about 6 years ago [Bind nginx on the same port for tcp and http](https://serverfault.com/questions/586209/bind-nginx-on-the-same-port-for-tcp-and-http)

However, has anything changed, is it possible for me to do something like:

```
stream {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        protocol http;
    }
    location /mysql {
        protocol tcp;
    }
}
```

Or must the`tcp` and `http` modules still be separate?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/586209/bind-nginx-on-the-same-port-for-tcp-and-http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not just a missing feature in Nginx that could be improved somehow in the future, but a protocol level incompatibility making it completely impossible.

In your example, the location path `/mysql` only exists within the HTTP protocol. In HTTP, the client starts the communication with a request:

```
GET /mysql HTTP/1.1
Hostname: example.com
```

The [MySQL Client/Server Protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html) is a totally different protocol which even starts the other way around: the server sending an [Initial Handshake Packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase-packets.html#packet-Protocol::Handshake), e.g.

> ```
> 36 00 00 00 0a 35 2e 35 2e 32 2d 6d 32 00 0b 00   6....5.5.2-m2... 
> 00 00 64 76 48 40 49 2d 43 4a 00 ff f7 08 02 00.  ..dvH@I-CJ...... 
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2a 34 64.  .............*
> 4d 7c 63 5a 77 6b 34 5e 5d 3a 00                  |cZwk4^]:.
> ```

Theoretically, TLS could make it possible to distinguish different services on the same TCP port based on the *Server Name Indication* (SNI) and forward the traffic to different upstream servers, even with different underlying protocols. However,

- AFAIK anything like that hasn't been implemented in Nginx.
- Your chosen example, MySQL Client/Server Protocol, doesn't start the communication with TLS, but the capability for TLS is [announced](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/ssl.html) in the Initial Handshake Packet, and the connection is upgraded to TLS, if both the server and the client supports it.
- Every standard protocol has its own port for TLS (or plain text with `STARTTLS`), and we are not running out of TCP ports, anyway. Therefore, there's no high demand for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

They still need to be separate. Otherwise nginx would need to be able to proxy mysql calls which it can't.